# redis / stdnet data model traceback

Tags: python, redis, nosql

I'm experimenting with [stdnet](http://lsbardel.github.io/python-stdnet/) and I'm having a challenge with what should be a relatively simple case.

If I populate my model (see below the `<hr>`) without specifying the value for the primary key, I get:

> stdnet.utils.exceptions.FieldValueError: {"author_id": "Field 'author_id' is required for '**main**.book'."}

```
    author1 = models[Author](name='Jeff Doyle')
```

However, adding a value for `id` makes the code work...

```
    author1 = models[Author](name='Jeff Doyle', id=1)
```

`Author.id` is `odm.AutoIdField()`. Since this is a hierarchical data model, I might be able to understand the requirement to manually add `id = odm.AutoIdField()` to my model.  However, the documentation says that the [odm.AutoIdField](http://lsbardel.github.io/python-stdnet/api/fields.html#stdnet.odm.AutoIdField) automatically generates the value for the primary keys.

My question: *Why do I need to specify a value for `id` manually when I populate my models?*

I'm running [stdnet](http://lsbardel.github.io/python-stdnet/) 0.8.2 w/ Cython, on Python 2.6.6 and Debian 6.0 (kernel 2.6.32-5-amd64).

---

**Working Example:**

```
from stdnet import odm

class Author(odm.StdModel):
    id = odm.AutoIdField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = odm.SymbolField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(odm.StdModel):
    id = odm.AutoIdField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    title = odm.CharField()
    author = odm.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "<Book '%s' by %s>" % (self.title, self.author)

if __name__=='__main__':
    models = odm.Router('redis://localhost:6379?db=0')
    models.register(Author)
    models.register(Book)

    session = models.session()
    session.begin()
    author1 = models[Author](name='Jeff Doyle', id=1)
    session.add(author1)
    book1 = models[Book](title='Routing TCP/IP, Volume 1', id=2, author=author1)
    session.add(book1)
    session.commit()
```

---

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdnet_example.py", line 31, in <module>
    session.commit()
...
stdnet.utils.exceptions.FieldValueError: {"author_id": "Field 'author_id' is required for '__main__.book'."}
```

Comment: Because you made it a "required" field

Comment: I also tried without `required`, but I still get the traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are trying to insert both the book and the author in the same session. So at the time of the commit, the author hasn't been saved to the database and thus doesn't have an id for the book to reference in the foreign key.

I think it should work if you commited the author before trying to add the book. Something like this:

```
session.begin()
author1 = models[Author](name='Jeff Doyle')
session.add(author1)
session.commit()

session.begin()
book1 = models[Book](title='Routing TCP/IP, Volume 1', author=author1)
session.add(book1)
session.commit()
```

I see there was an issue raised on GitHub by someone having a similar problem to you, and there is [a response in the comments](https://github.com/lsbardel/python-stdnet/issues/62#issuecomment-20230530) from the author of stdnet. I think he is basically saying the same thing as me, but you can read it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The best (most efficient) way is to code as follow:

```
with models.session().begin() as t1:
    for author in ['Leo Tolstoy', 'unknown ghostwriter']:
        t1.add(models.author(name=author))
    publisher = t1.add(models.publisher(name='Penguin Books'))
```

At this point, authors and publisher are saved, in addition authors can be retrieved from the transaction `saved` attribute:

```
authors = t1.saved['author']
```

You can now create the books:

```
with models.session().begin() as t2:
    for title in ['Anna Karenina', 'War and Peace']:
        t2.add(models.book(name=title, publisher=publisher))
```

And now you can add the authors via the last transaction:

```
books = t2.saved['book']

with models.session().begin() as t3:
    for book in books:
        # add the book to the transaction
        t3.add(book)
        for author in authors:
             book.authors.push_back(author)
```

---

All the code above assumes you're using this Model definition:

```
import sys

from stdnet import odm

class Publisher(odm.StdModel):
    name = odm.SymbolField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(odm.StdModel):
    name = odm.SymbolField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(odm.StdModel):
    name = odm.CharField()
    authors = odm.ListField(model=Author)
    publisher = odm.ForeignKey(Publisher, related_name='publishers')


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "<Book '%s' by %s>" % (self.name, self.authors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't know the library(I actually have been looking for this, so thanks :) ). I think that the `models.register` will not only register the model in the your program, but also on the Redis server. So you either have to purge the database if you can, or find some way to change model.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using different syntax than James Holderness recommended; his answer was helpful, but the syntax I used in the original question didn't seem to work well with complex `odm.ForeignKey` models.  I ultimately switched to different syntax, which I'm documenting here because the `python-stdnet 0.8` docs are a bit confusing.

**Building the DB:**

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    ## assuming we have a test redis db at localhost:6379
    models = odm.Router('redis://localhost:6379?db=0')
    models.register(Publisher)
    models.register(Author)
    models.register(Book)
    session = models.session()

    session.begin()  # Start a redis session
    authors = list()
    for author in ['Leo Tolstoy', 'unknown ghostwriter']:
        authors.append(models.author.new(name=author))
    publisher = models.publisher.new(name='Penguin Books')
    session.commit()

    for title in ['Anna Karenina', 'War and Peace']:
        print "Writing", title
        book = models.book.new(name=title, publisher=publisher)
        for author in authors:
            book.authors.push_back(author)  # push_back() appends to odm.ListField
    session.commit()  # Write to the redis db
```

**Querying the DB:**

```
    ## assuming we have a test redis db at localhost:6379
    models = odm.Router('redis://localhost:6379?db=0')
    models.register(Publisher)
    models.register(Author)
    models.register(Book)
    session = models.session()

    qs = models.book.filter(name__contains='War and Peace') # search Book.name
    print "You found", list(qs)
```

**Model Definitions** (Used to both build and query):

```
import sys

from stdnet import odm

class Publisher(odm.StdModel):
    name = odm.SymbolField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(odm.StdModel):
    name = odm.SymbolField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(odm.StdModel):
    name = odm.CharField()
    authors = odm.ListField(model=Author)
    publisher = odm.ForeignKey(Publisher, related_name='publishers')


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "<Book '%s' by %s>" % (self.name, self.authors)
```

Comment: `models.book.new` does not use the session you start, it is a convenience method to immediately create a new model.